# Response very slow in IE-8

Tags: javascript, html, doctype

I have a strange issue with IE-8 when my table contains around 1000 records. Issue is that I have a table with 1000 records containing some text boxes to get input from user. When I perform some input/tab operation on that table, the response is very slow I mean typed characters are displaying late.

I figured out that when we remove DOCTYPE from that page, response is fast. I am using apache tiles and don't know how to ignore DOCTYPE for specific page only.

There is no problem with  javascript/code like when I remove the functions also response is slow.

Comment: do you have a javascript event handler bound to the change/keypress event(s) of the textboxes?

Comment: Yes, I have onFocus,onChange,onBlur events bounded to that text box.

Comment: ...Then please include the code for those...  It's going to be those that are slowing the page down.

Comment: I should think so - but as a guess do any of these methods check the other text boxes?  Actually - put it another way - if you take the javascript handlers out, does the page go really fast again?

Comment: No. When I tested in IE-7 its fast but when I checked in IE-8 its slow. Actually I see response is fast when I remove DOCTYPE from the page in IE-8

Comment: What is the method you use to remove the doctype from that page?

Comment: remove means just delete the line.

Comment: @Ran did you figure out this issue? I am having the same problem. All script execution is also slow when I insert the doctype.